# Git Clone a repository sitting on a Linux server through a Linux jump host onto a Windows local hard drive

Tags: linux, windows-7, git

Ok so I have a Windows machine and I want to clone a git repository from a Linux Server A but I can only access Server A through another Linux Server B.

From the Windows machine Git Bash, I can ssh into Server A through Server B:

'''
ssh -J username@serverB username@serverA
'''

But how do I incorporate that into my git clone command?

Comment: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/

Comment: Nice! Brilliant guide! Thanks!